# Реализация метода возврата сообщения

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Как реализовать метод `GetFirstMessage()`? Использовать вторую коллекцию?

```
public interface IMessenger
{
    void SendMessage(string message); //отправить сообщение
    string GetLastMessage(); //получить последнее сообщение
    string GetFirstMessage(); //получить первое сообщение
}
```

И сам код:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Messenger : IMessenger
    {
        Stack<string> numbers = new Stack<string>();
        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            numbers.Push(message);
        }

        public string GetLastMessage()
        {
            if (numbers.Count != 0)
                return numbers.Pop();
            else return null;                
        }
    }

    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var messenger = new Messenger();
            messenger.SendMessage("Hello");
            messenger.SendMessage("world");
            messenger.SendMessage("!");
            Console.WriteLine(messenger.GetLastMessage());
            Console.WriteLine(messenger.GetLastMessage());
            Console.WriteLine(messenger.GetLastMessage());
            Console.WriteLine(messenger.GetLastMessage());
            Console.Read();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Очевидно вы выбрали неподходящую коллекцию, вам нужна двусторонняя очередь

Comment: @Андрей: Пришёл сюда написать такой же комментарий.

Comment: @tym32167, а зачем ответ удалили, LinkedList на некоторых операциях не медленнее чем List, но в данном случае он ведь гораздо удобнее. Не нужно забывать, что при добавлении/удалении элементов придется расширять внутренний массив List, а при вставке в начало вообще копировать в другой массив. Так что использовать LinkedList здесь уместно, а если ТС недостаточно производительности - можно найти готовое решение, их, благо, хватает. Так что верните ответ (я свой такой же не успел опубликовать).

Comment: @Андрей Я просто на атомате написал ответ и на автомате удалил, голова слабо соображает от недосыпа :) Вернул как было

Answer (score 3):

В простейшем случае я бы предложил поглядеть на [LinkedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class Messenger : IMessenger
{
    LinkedList<string> numbers = new LinkedList<string>();
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        numbers.AddLast(message);
    }

    public string GetLastMessage()
    {
        if (numbers.Count != 0)
        {
            var last = numbers.Last;
            numbers.RemoveLast();
            return last.Value;
        }
        else return null;
    }

    public string GetFirstMessage()
    {
        if (numbers.Count != 0)
        {
            var first = numbers.First;
            numbers.RemoveFirst();
            return first.Value;
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Обычный `List` будет [быстрее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12466884/4924596)

Comment: Вернул ответ так как он не так уж плох. Кстати, @RusArt, не факт что быстрей, тут нет же цикла по элементам, а в замерах по вашей ссылке - есть.

Comment: @RusArt, а насколько List будет неудобнее в этом конкретном примере? Ну и при добавлении элементов List надо будет расширять внутренний массив, при вставке в начало - так вообще каждый раз... А если уж ТС будет не хватать производительности - можно будет улучшить или взять готовое решение, благо они гуглятся на раз

Comment: У меня в тесте эти методы не сработают, у меня идет по порядку один раз ввод и два разных getov потом var messenger = new Messenger(); 
messenger.SendMessage("Hello");
messenger.SendMessage("world");
messenger.SendMessage("!");

messenger.GetLastMessage(); // "!"
messenger.GetLastMessage(); // "world"
messenger.GetLastMessage(); // "Hello"
messenger.GetLastMessage(); // null

messenger.GetFirstMessage(); // "Hello"
messenger.GetFirstMessage(); // "world"
messenger.GetFirstMessage(); // "!"
messenger.GetFirstMessage(); // null

Comment: @VictorRadin, после запроса элемента (первого или последнего), он удаляется из очереди, вам нужно другое поведение?

Comment: Спасибо, подсказали в каком направлении копать, буду разбираться

Comment: @RusArt не "будет быстрее" - это разные коллекции с разной сложностью для разных операций. Об этом, кстати, прямо сказано [в комменте к ответу по вашей ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169973/when-should-i-use-a-list-vs-a-linkedlist/12466884#comment42538277_12466884). и в соседних с ним ответах. просто топикастер там поставил зеленую галочку наугад.